# 8 children and 12 men complete the work in 9 days. If each child is half as efficient as a man, how long will 12 men finish the same work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Eight children and twelve men complete a certain piece of work in 9 days. If each child is half as efficient as a man, then in how many days will 12 men finish the same work?

$8C+12M=9$ days where $C$ stands for children and $M$ stands for men

$C=1/2M$

$4M+12M=9$

$16M=9$

$1M=9/16$

$12M=9/16*12$ days.

But this is not the correct answer
I will be really grateful if someone will help me with this question

Comment: More workers means less time to do the job. Your equations imply it is more. It helps to write down what the variables mean, both to avoid this type of error and to help your readers understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Output equals labor-force * productivty * time.

$(8 c + 12 m)*9 = 1$

Or, this crew completes 1/9 the project per day.

$8 c + 12 m = \frac 19$

Children are half as productive as men

$c = \frac 12 m\\
16 m = \frac 19\\
12 m = \frac 34 \frac 19 = \frac 1{12}$

$12$ men complete $\frac 1{12}$ the project per day.  Or complete the project in 12 days.